$RCA_0$ implies very recursive planar graph has a recursive 4 colouring function
In Bean's effective coloration, he shows that there is a recursive planar graph but without any recursive 4-coloring function. Can this fact be a witness that $\textbf{RCA}_0$ can not imply every recursive planar graph has a recursive 4 coloring function?

Who is "Mr Bean" in this context ? What is "effective coloration" ? and $RCA_0$ ? Please give references.

@JeanMarie The latter two terms are completely standard in this subject.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272247?saml_data=eyJzYW1sVG9rZW4iOiI1Y2Y4ZjVmZi03MWM2LTQ3YmItOTI3OS00ODQ4MTVhZTEwNWYiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1tMjNqMmxAbGVlZHMuYWMudWsiLCJpbnN0aXR1dGlvbklkcyI6WyJiOTNlMGVjMC0wMDkzLTRlZmMtYjM4ZS0wODZmYmRmNWE1ZDgiXX0

This link is the paper for the effective coloration by Bean

@Goliath, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read this thread and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very bad and low-quality question.

@Angelo Sorry about that, I will improve the quality of my question next time

About the question you asked: The result you quoted from Bean  shows that "every recursive planar graph has a recursive $4$-coloring" can't be proved in $RCA_0$ or even in ZFC, because it's false.
Now about the question you presumably intended to ask: The Bean result implies that $RCA_0$ can't prove "every planar graph has a $4$-coloring." (I hope "planar" can be defined in $RCA_0$.) The point is that $RCA_0$ has a model in which the only sets are the recursive ones.
I agree with the part of Jean Marie's comment asking for a reference  for Bean's result. But I disagree with the part about "effective coloration" and "$RCA_0$", as these seem perfectly standard and clear to me.

Thanks for your explanation. $RCA_0$ doesn't prove every planar graph has a recursive 4-colouring function is because there is a model of $RCA_0$ which just consists of recursive set. I am sorry I am not so clear for the part of model theory. Which theorem show that if there is a model of theory T doesn't satisfy the formula $\theta$, then T can't prove $\theta$. Is it soundness theorem?

@Goliath Yes, soundness means that anything provable from a theory $T$ must be true in all models of $T$.

I see thanks for your explanation.
